# C - System Calls - Partition of array for N children processes -

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, system-calls

First of all thank you for the help in advance. I have to write a program in which I pass an element to search from terminal and in which the parent process divides the array (consisting of random numbers) of dimensions - defined by terminal - in equal parts, each managed by a child process with the same code. Each child takes care of looking for the element in a part of the array, in order to divide fairly the job among the children processes.

The problem is that I don't know how to make this partition, without an array sorted. I thought I could do kind of Merge/Cocktail or Quick Sort,
but I think it is overabundant and useless for this task.

Here it is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

    int partition(int x, int y);

    int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
      int i, j, result, state_wait, *v, n_children, dim, random_number;
      int elem,div,lower,higher;
      pid_t pid;
      srand(time(NULL));
      if(argc<4){
        fprintf(stderr,"Insufficient parameters\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      n_children=atoi(argv[1]);
      if(n_children<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Enter a positive number of children\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      dim=atoi(argv[2]);
      if(dim<0||dim>n_children){
        fprintf(stderr,"Enter a valid size\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      elem=atoi(argv[3]);
      fprintf(stdout,"F: Father || PID = %d\n",getpid());   
      v=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*dim);
      fprintf(stdout,"F: VECTOR:\n\n");
      for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
        v[i]=rand();
        fprintf(stdout,"(%d) v[%d] number = %d\n",i,i,v[i]);
      }
      for(j=0;j<n_children;j++){
        if(fork()==0){
          fprintf("F: Child N. = %d || PID = %d\n",i,getpid());
          div=partition(dim,n_children);
          //lower=? j*div?
          higher=lower+div-1; //except the final case when it is dim-1
          result=search(lower,higher,&elem);
        }
      }
    }

    int partition(int x, int y){
      int div=(x/y); //If I had a vector of 1000 elem., work on them must be fairly distributed among the children
      //number of elements each group
      if((x-div)>1)
        div=(x/y)+1;
      return div;
        }
    int search(int lower,int higher, int*elem){
      int i;
      for(i=lower;i<=higher;i++){
        if(v[i]==elem){
          fprintf(stdout,"Element found [position = %d]\n",i);
          exit(1);
        }
      }
      exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but **never** use `atoi()`.  It not only provides no error detection, per the C standard upon an error [undefined behavior is invoked](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1): "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."  Use something like `strtol()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use file descriptors for communication between processes. This is called a pipe. After that, you can split the array into the number of child processes available, perhaps including the parent one. Store these split parts in the pipe that you created. Let the child process fetch for the element in the file descriptor! I don't think it matters if the array is sorted or not, the task is divided by N (if N is the number of children) anyway. Search for 
`man 2 pipe`
in the linux (or MacOS) terminal for more information!

Comment: No I should use only the system call wait/waitpid, but I will keep that in mind, thanks.